# Laravel lang resetting to ENGLISH with POST route

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, parameters, localization

So here is my problem, I'm able to use Localization with Laravel. I've been using it on GET route, the problem occur with my POST route. For example, I'm in french on my registration page, when I click on register, once I enter my controller, the language is reset to english, but it must not be reset, because my controller is supposed to return a view with a text, so this view is supposed to be in the right language. I tought I could pass the lang through URL parameter, but since it is a POST I cannot and I must not use GET because it's a registration form. The thing is in my route I set the lang to what the lang is already, since it is already in french, from when I accessed the registration page, it should something like lang = 'fr', but no the program act like each time it set the lang to french, to second after it reset it to english. I've been stuck on this for a while and I cannot see the solution, can someone help me ?

**Here is my 'french' registration form:**

[image]
[image]

**Here is the route 'register' (When you click on register/inscription):**
[image]

**Here is a part of my controller:**
[image]

**Here is the view my controller returns (It is supposed to be written 'fr' not 'en'):**
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help and your time !

Comment: post code, not pictures of code

Comment: Your code `App::setLocale(app()->getlocale())` does nothing.  It just sets the locale to the existing value

Comment: Yeah I knew that, but I though that maybe the local value was right and I simply had to reset it to....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, now when I enter a page like to registration page I do this
[image]

And in the function that is triggered when clicking register/inscription I added this at the beginning
[image]